# Word for an idea that appears often in literature/film?

Tags: meaning

The closest thing I can come up with is *trope*, but it doesn't quite embody what I'm after.

Ex) The idea of having to balance life with work comes up often in film and television. It is a common ____.

Comment: theme ?  seems too easy to write up?

Comment: What's wrong with "trope" or "cliche"?

Comment: if it were more about what the story revolved around ... more of a pretense, you might call it a "device" or plot device https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_device  I really think you are looking for "theme" .. perhaps you can elaborate why that grade school level vocabulary word doesn't work ?

Comment: Please explain to us what you find wrong with the synonyms of "trope" and "cliche".

Answer (score 1):

As @Tom22 wrote in the comments, "theme" does sound acceptable, but if you are looking for a different word, "motif" seems to fit and hasn't been suggested here before.